# How to find the sd of two columns of matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, transpose

If I have a matrix which contains 6 variable,if I want to find the sd of (col1 and col1), (col1 and col2), (col1 and col6),......(col6 and col6),  and return a 6*6 matrix. What function should I use? (sd: Standard Deviation)

Thanks very much.

Comment: `sd`?? Do you mean covariance??

Comment: I mean standard deviation

Comment: I've gotta say, it is a very unusual request to want the standard devation of pairs of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create some sample data

```
set.seed(1)
m <- replicate(6, rnorm(5)) # make a matrix with 6 columns
```

You can use `expand.grid` to get all possible combinations, then loop through all combinations using `apply`.  Finally, wrap the result in `matrix`

```
matrix(apply(expand.grid(1:6, 1:6), 1, function(x) sd(m[, x])), ncol=6)
#              [,1]         [,2]        [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]
# [1,] 0.9060766593 0.7805859575 1.187979366 0.7326776974 1.0258159472 0.8334359580
# [2,] 0.7805859575 0.6305829418 1.095413861 0.5692800481 0.9169484342 0.6960691132
# [3,] 1.1879793664 1.0954138606 1.413152368 1.0695148355 1.2806974048 1.1228262280
# [4,] 0.7326776974 0.5692800481 1.069514836 0.4382343292 0.8814506207 0.7057912762
# [5,] 1.0258159472 0.9169484342 1.280697405 0.8814506207 1.1324043901 0.9556076127
# [6,] 0.8334359580 0.6960691132 1.122826228 0.7057912762 0.9556076127 0.6643807746
```

Comment: If I don't want to use expand.grid, what else can I use?

Comment: The seealso section of `?expand.grid` points to `combn`: `mat <- matrix(ncol=6, nrow=6); mat[lower.tri(mat)] <-  combn(1:6, 2, FUN=function(x) sd(m[, x])); mat`.  You could also nest some loops.  What's wrong with `expand.grid`?